# Typescript allowing access to an undefined object property

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to access keys from an object via a function, and if the value doesn't exist, check the next object. I understand the error, but I'm not sure how to handle this situation properly, for example allowing TS to access a missing property.

```
// constants with transformed values
const firstList = { foo: "a value" }
const secondList = { bar: "another value" }

function getValue( key: keyof typeof firstList | keyof typeof secondList ) {
    let val = firstList[key]
    if (val != undefined) return val
    return secondList[key]
}
```

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"foo"
> | "bar"' can't be used to index type '{ foo: string; }'.   Property
> 'bar' does not exist on type '{ foo: string; }'.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

```js
// constants with transformed values
const firstList = { foo: "a value" }
const secondList = { bar: "another value" }

const isAllowedKey = <Obj extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>>(obj: Obj, prop: PropertyKey)
    : prop is keyof Obj =>
    Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);


function getValue(key: keyof typeof firstList | keyof typeof secondList) {

    if (isAllowedKey(firstList, key)) {
        let val = key

        if (val != undefined) {
            return val
        }
    } else {
        return secondList[key]

    }

    // We should cover all pathes
    return undefined
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/ND2LxW)

As you might have noticed, I have added third path: `return undefined`, this is because in order to infer `bar` key, you need to put it into `else` branch. However with `if\else` we ended up in a situation when `return undefined` is not reachable but TS complains about covering all pathes

Comment: this works for me as well thanks! Also helped me understand this better. I'm still stuck on the `unknown` but I'll keep at it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider changing your implementation, and adding a type guard:

```
function isKeyIn<K extends string, T extends object>(key: K, value: T): key is keyof T & K {
    return key in value;
}

function getValue( key: keyof typeof firstList | keyof typeof secondList ) {
    return isKeyIn(key, firstList) ? firstList[key] : secondList[key];
}
```

See [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) in the handbook.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NrXq2W)

Comment: A type predicate! That's perfect thanks @caTS!

Comment: I've been staring at your isKeyIn function trying to make sense of it, I didn't realize `key in value` was possible.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting a `Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'object'.: This type parameter might need an extends object constraint.` from the function

Comment: @Sean I believe I fixed it by changing the constraints, but you should also see captain-yossarian's answer.